# What level will I be on Borderlands 2 after completing the main game and all DLC?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have just completed Borderlands 2 main campaign and all of the side quests (except for the infamous Terrormorphus) and am sat at level 35. I am aiming to hit level 50, and feel that instead of just grinding through TVHM I might enjoy playing the DLC instead (I will be getting this either way).

I am just curious to know, what level I would be after completing all of the current DLC?

I know it's tricky to predict as people have played the DLC at different times, but I am sure someone must have completed it all before reaching level 50.

Comment: Surely your level depends on how many bad guys you kill, stuff you find etc. There might be a range of levels, but there'd be no guarantee you'll hit a particular level.

Comment: I appreciate that but an average is what I am after - I recall reading that on average the main game will sit you at level 34-35 which matches with my experience, so there must be a rough idea? - Sorry, was using my phone which apparently hadn't loaded the page fully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your first playthrough all enemies (except raid bosses) are capped at level 30. It's very hard to level up past about level 35 killing them because by then you'll be getting 1xp per kill.

On your second playthrough the enemies re-scale and level you up to 50, which is the current cap.

If you go through playthrough one you should be about level 35 by the end. None of the DLC will take you past that, because the enemies will still be capped at 30.

If you want to get to level 50 start TVHM mode, you will still be able to start the DLC right from the beginning.

Note that you can always switch back (via the character select menu) to playthrough one, and you keep all your kit between both, so there's really no excuse not to go to TVHM

Answer (score -4):

Im currently level 44 and have done all DLC and missions except for 3 except for missions that are level 50 only. So its not hard at all to level up past 35.