# What missions must be completed in the main game, to avoid having them spoiled in Dragon's Keep?

Tags: borderlands-2

There's only a handful of *big* events or facts to be spoiled that I can think of in the main Borderlands 2 game. In no particular order:

> - Angel is not an AI - she is a siren.
>  - Angel has been manipulating the Vault Hunters on Jack's behalf since the first game.
>  - Angel is Jack's daughter.
>  - You kill Angel.
>  - Jack kills Roland.
>  - Jack kills Bloodwing.

I'm aware there are *some* spoilers (particularly the last two items on the above list) in Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon's Keep, but I haven't played all the way through to know what others there might be.

If the above list is all there is, then I believe a player only needs to complete up to the following point in the main game in order to be "spoiler safe" going into Dragon's Keep:

> Where Angels Fear to Tread (Part 1)

Is this correct, or does Dragon's Keep have other significant spoilers from later on in the Story missions (or in some sidequests) that I haven't thought of? What are all the main game spoilers in Dragon's Keep, and what missions does a player need to complete in the main game to avoid them?

(Of course, please use spoiler notation where appropriate, by putting `>!` at the start of lines containing spoilers.)

Note: This question is not about preparation for DLCs in terms of game mechanics such as player leveling. I only want to know what part of the *main story* should be completed to avoid discontinuity and spoilers in this particular DLC.

Comment: Ok, I get the edit. Why the down-vote?

Comment: Duplicate.  See this answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/101772/42984

Comment: @DavidStarkey That's no reason for a down-vote, but thanks for the info. However, this is not a duplicate of the suggested thread. The other "When should I start the DLC" thread focuses on what level a player should be to match up to the difficulty level of a DLC. It's not concerned with primary game spoilers like this is. I've modified the title of this question to better reflect its intent and differentiate it from the other.

Comment: Although the other question could be improved to answer yours, I see value in the different answers.

Comment: @Iszi I didn't down-vote and the spoilers thing is a good question but you could probably map it to your level.

Comment: @DavidStarkey A player's level, at any given point in their game experience, is an incredibly difficult (if not impossible) thing to predict in Borderlands. You gain XP by killing enemies and finishing quests, but the *vast majority* of enemies and quests are really optional. You also always have the option of opening the game up to other players (local or online) to help compensate for any situations where you're under-leveled.

Comment: @DavidStarkey It would be an interesting experiment to see how low-leveled one could stay, and still complete all the story missions, if they have a level 50+ friend escort them through the entire game and *only* take care of the *bare essential* enemies and quests. At the other extreme, you could prioritize sidequests and kill every single enemy (and respawned enemy) in your path and end up significantly over-leveled wherever you go for most of the game. This is why [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102335/) was so heavily down-voted and closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basicly Tiny Tina DLC continues straight from where the main game ends (Chronologically)
There is no references into the earlier 3 DLC, allthough some characters from those DLCs are present in this one.

As far as spoilers go, there is no major spoilers outside of those you have listed, the 4th DLC references more into other games, movies and internet culture as a whole in not-so-subtle-way =P

You should start the DLC on true vault hunter mode, right after you've beaten the main game in normal mode. (It seems like the dlc was meant to be played from level 35+)

Comment: Thanks for the verification. I just finished the main story of the DLC last night (I was surprised at how short it was, but loved the ending!) and it seems like my original list was indeed right on. There may be some other stuff in some side-quests I haven't done yet, though.

Comment: All the side quests are references to popular games, movies and TV shows, no spoilers there =)